# To get Graphical Info reader in El Capitan?

Tags: command-line, macos

Graphical info reader is the reader which colorises links in the info pages. I know there are good options in OS X but I cannot find them. 
I do `home search info` and I get

```
homebrew/science/clinfo    media-info                 shared-mime-info         
ipinfo                     mp3info                    texinfo                  
jpeginfo                   pinfo                    
homebrew/emacs/pkg-info                  Caskroom/cask/mac-informer             
homebrew/games/inform6                   Caskroom/cask/mediainfo                
Caskroom/cask/inform                     Caskroom/cask/pdfinfo
```

but nothing seems to be a info -pages reader.

---

How can you get a graphical reader of info -pages in El Capitan?

Comment: Cocoa emacs :) (Emacs.app or Aquamacs)

Comment: @Mark Yes, it is one option. Please, add your proposal to get and use it for reading info files as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it isn't strictly graphical, I find [`pinfo`](https://alioth.debian.org/projects/pinfo/) to be much more usable than most alternatives for reading info pages, and it can also read man pages. `pinfo` can be installed with `brew install pinfo`. Its key bindings, appearance, and behavior can be configured in a rudimentary fashion by editing `/usr/local/etc/pinforc`.

If you want to use `pinfo` in a graphical environment, I'd suggest creating a script that runs it inside your favorite terminal.

---

The standard GNU `info` reader (which is also terminal-based) is installed as part of the `texinfo` package in Homebrew, but [according to the `info` docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html#Stand_002dalone-Info),

> Emacs Info and stand-alone Info have nearly identical user interfaces, although customization and other details are different

For me, that makes the standard `info` reader a no-go as well. (I'm also a Dvorak/Vim user)

---

Another option is to use the `/usr/local/Cellar/texinfo/*/bin/texi2any` program (from the `texinfo` package) with the `--html` option to convert info pages to HTML, and then view them in a web browser. This requires a lot of up-front work before reading them, but could be worth it if you *really* prefer a graphical reader.

Comment: One other caveat I noticed is that with [keg-only packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015285/understand-homebrew-and-keg-only-dependencies), since their info files are also not linked into the `/usr/local/share/info` tree, you have to specify their full path when viewing them. With `pinfo`: `pinfo -f /usr/local/Cellar/readline/*/share/info/readline.info`

Comment: How do you read man pages yourself?

Comment: I always use `pinfo` in a terminal; I've used it for years, and since it defaults to `lynx`-style navigation, it's really easy to get the hang of. (Up and Down select links on the page, Right or Enter follows the current link, and Left goes back)

Comment: In your pointed out thread, you can check which files are keg-only by `otool -L /usr/local/Cellar/vips/???/lib/*‌​.dylib`.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious one is emacs itself as info is its documentation format

The Apple supplied emacs does do this in the terminal as do more up to date ones

There are graphical versions [Emacs.app](https://emacsformacosx.com) for pure emacs and [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org) trying to be more like a standard OSX app.

If you need this from the command line other make .info files opened by the emacs app and use the command open or use emacsclient

Comment: Can you please add short summary of the keys how you read those info pages in Emacs. I am Vim and Dvorak user :)

Comment: @Masi info is originally the Emacs/Gnu documentation project and so uses standard Emacs keys (see many docs) which NeXT copied as its shortcut keys in what became OSX so see OSX key shortcuts as well

Comment: How can you open `info gtime` in Aquamacs?